# hide Subtitles menu from mpmoviecontrol in ios 7

Tags: ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

In iOS 7 when i push the mpmovieplayercontroller to screen there is an "Audio & Subtitles" menu item. However, it does not in ios 6. **(it appears only in stream video playing)**

Are there any way to hide this menu ?

BTW, i have tried 4 MPMovieControlStyle and none of them hide this menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Alternate Track button appears and how made it hidden.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1801/_index.html

Comment: More Specifically the source material will have to include:
`CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE` on the `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` tag to remove the Button.